# Running a cloud function from express route

Tags: express, parse-server

Using the new parse server is there a way to call a function in the main.js file from the index.js?
Example is to allow an endpoint for a third party so they can post a set of data without needed the application_id or any keys.

Old hosted parse.com allowed like this;

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('functionname' data);
}
```

But I cannot get the routing to work in parse-server.

Comment: That should work. Can you update your question with any errors you get?

Comment: Any update/fix/work around on this? I am having a similar issue

Answer (score -1):

Maybe later but can help!

Just write your cloud code cloud/main.js, or include your own packages there. and call Parse.Cloud.run(for js) on the client side. You have to write secure code on cloud/main.js to protect your server and datas.